# mysql group_concat, does size limit apply only to returning value?

Tags: mysql, md5, group-concat

Without going into details of why, i want to do a join based on the result of a group_concat function. (needless to say, i can't change max length parameter,but plan to capture a hash i can use to join) 
From the looks of it i'm getting different values when using md5.
eg.

```
select CONVERT(md5(group_concat(mycolumn))  USING utf8) ...
```

returns a different result from pasting the group_concat value into quotes

```
select CONVERT(md5(group_concat('truncated value returned by group_concat...')) USING utf8)
```

can i assume that group_concat returns complete result to the md5 function, or could the difference be caused by something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` does *not* return the complete results to `MD5`.  I tested it specifically:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 5;
SELECT MD5(GROUP_CONCAT('123456'));
-- 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
SET group_concat_max_len = 999;
SELECT MD5(GROUP_CONCAT('123456'));
-- e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

If you can't change `group_concat_max_len`, you're going to have to find another way.

Answer (score 2):

The default limit for `group_concat` is 1024, as clearly explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024.

You can change this by changing seting the `group_concat_max_len` system variable.

This would affect both results that you see and arguments to functions.

In addition, the tool you are using to fetch the results may further truncate the return value.

And finally, if you are using `group_concat()` like this, then you should explicitly use an `order by` clause.  The ordering is not guaranteed.  In practice, I don't think it will change between runs if the underlying data does not change.  However, deleting and inserting records could change the ordering.

Comment: indeed i planned to order it as well...but now looks like it's back to the drawing board

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `order by`.  I found that the order chosen is affected by nonintuitive factors (like the mysql version or the bounds of a nearby `where id between x and y` clause).

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to first `md5(concat())` the row, which would reduce the size to 32 bytes per row, and then `group_concat` the whole thing.  This would allow you to get hashes of `floor(group_concat_max_len / 33)` rows at a time (don't forget commas).

I do something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369193/1054322).

If that still doesn't fit inside your `group_concat_max_len` then you could `GROUP BY` something that yields groups smaller than `floor(group_concat_max_len / 33)` rows, hash those, and then hash those hashes (again in groups less than...).  It would be ugly, but you could continue to nest as deeply as is necessary to hash as many rows as you need.

Or you could ask somebody with power to modify `group_concat_max_len` under threat of thrashing their CPU with the above strategy.