# How can I use group_concat on an entire subquery?

Tags: python, mysql

...without making unnecessary comparisons

I want to get an md5 hash of a range of rows. Due to bandwidth limitations, I want it to happen server-side.

This works:

```
create table some_table (id int auto_increment,
                         col1 varchar(1),
                         col2 int,
                         primary key (id));

insert into some_table (col1, col2)
                values ('a', 1),
                       ('b', 11),
                       ('c', 12),
                       ('d', 25),
                       ('e', 50);

select group_concat(id,col1,col2) from
    (select * from some_table
     where id >= 2 and id < 5
     order by id desc) as some_table
group by 1 = 1;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
| group_concat(id,col1,col2) |
+----------------------------+
| 2b11,3c12,4d25             |
+----------------------------+
```

And with the hash:

```
select md5(group_concat(id,col1,col2)) from
    (select * from some_table
     where id >= 2 and id < 5
     order by id desc) as some_table
group by 1 = 1;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------+
| md5(group_concat(id,col1,col2))  |
+----------------------------------+
| 32c1f1dd34d3ebd33ca7d95f3411888e |
+----------------------------------+
```

But I feel like there should be a better way.

Particularly, I want to avoid comparing 1 with 1 millions of times, something I found necessary in order to get the row range into a group, which I needed in order to use `group_concat`, which I needed in order to use `md5` on mutiple rows.

Is there a way to use `group_concat` (or similar) on a row range, without the needless comparison?

**Edit**

I want to hash multiple rows so that I can compare the resulting hashes on different servers.  If they are different I can conclude that there is a difference in the rows returned by the subquery.

Comment: Again this question i saw this question yesterday also?  Whats `group by 1 = 1` suppost to do because basically it's the same as `GROUP BY 1`?

Comment: When you pointed out the mistake, I deleted the post because I didn't want to waste anybody's time since it clearly had a problem.  Sorry I wasted yours.  I fixed the problem and reposted it.  If that's not the right way to proceed, I'm sorry.  -- I guess my problem is that I don't understand how mysql treats booleans.  Group by 1 is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No it's ok i think.. but i don't completly understand what you are trying to compare with the hashes..

Comment: I think the right question here is why do you need to concat everything to generate the hash. You want to generate a hash based on a range of rows but you didn't explain what for you will use it. The bandwidth may not even be a problem if you approach your requirement with the right solution. So try explaining why are you doing it. Why exactly do you need to generate a md5 in a range? **With what will you compare it to and how?**

Comment: "why do you need to concat everything to generate the hash." to "answer" @JorgeCampos comment.  You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` because `GROUP_CONCAT` can "merge" values over multiple records within a group into one string https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have a large database that I need to sync a subset of to a test environment.  I want to hash the relevant rows to see if they have changes that need to be transferred to the test environment.  I will be comparing the hash to the output of the same query in the test environment.

Comment: "I was not asking how group_concat works (about 15y xp mysql), please re-read my comment." The "answer" how GROUP_CONCAT works was meant for the topicstarter @JorgeCampos you misinterpreted the comment because of the @ yourname i geuss

Comment: I was trying to boil it down to just my question, which @RaymondNijland answered by pointing out that 1 = 1 can be simplified to 1.  The bigger picture of what I'm up to can be seen here https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/mysqlslice/blob/master/mysqlslice/sync.py in the function "find_diff_intervals"

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService Ok, now you should add this info to your question. Without it  it seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ooh, sorry then. :)

Comment: Besides `GROUP BY 1` simply means `GROUP BY the first column` in MySQL which is the same as `group_concat(id,col1,col2)` @MatrixManAtYrService .. iám also going to add the tag Python because off the added code.

Comment: why not simply do a dump from production and restore it in test? By the time your script finishes the checking (or even start) the production may already have changed. The dump **may** be faster than this manual difference checking... or dump and restore just that one table

Comment: I'm sorry @RaymondNijland, I spoke too soon.  What I want is to group the entire subquery into a single group, so I can use group_concat on it.  `GROUP BY 1` gives the error `ERROR 1056 (42000): Can't group on 'group_concat(id,col1,col2)'`

Comment: Then MySQL handles `GROUP BY 1 = 1` simply as 1 or true.

Comment: completing the @RaymondNijland statement: which is equivalent to not have the group by at all.

Comment: Dumping from production and restoring in test takes a good six hours (very slow connection).  I can scan for changes in 10k row chunks in just minutes.  In the typical case, only two or three chunks actually need transferring.

Comment: You can just dump that table with your where range (so the specific subset)... no need to dump everything or even the whole table.

Comment: So it's like 40% of the table is relevant for the test, and 2% of that is likely to have changed since yesterday.  A `where` clause in the `mysqldump` command handles the 40% but not the 2%.   I usualy do `mysqldump | gzip --rsyncable` and then rsync  the dump on top of yesterday's (which trims the network traffic to 2%) but then I still need to wait for the whole 40% to load on the receiving end.  I suppose I could make a copy before clobbering with rsync and then load only the statements that differ...

Comment: Ok, understood. I would then have a `last_change_date default now()` column in the production database (same in test) then i would just get for the subset the max or min last date change in both databases and compare... no need to concat anything and it would be way faster

Comment: That sounds like a very reasonable change.  There is a council of elders that reviews database changes, and making reasonable requests of them is fraught with peril :-/  Nobody cares what my test code does though....

Also, "just don't do a group by" is the answer to my question.  I'll accept it if you post it.

Comment: Then it should be @RaymondNijland to post it since he was the one to mention it first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to omit `group by 1 = 1` entirely.  I had assumed that `group_concat` would require that I provide it a group, but it can be used directly on a subquery, like so:

```
select group_concat(id,col1,col2) from
    (select * from some_table
     where id >= 2 and id < 5
     order by id desc) as some_table;
```

---

Be aware that null values will need to be cast to something concat-friendly, like so:

```
insert into some_table (col1, col2)
                values ('a', 1),
                       ('b', 11),
                       ('c', NULL),
                       ('d', 25),
                       ('e', 50);

select group_concat(id, col1, col2) from
    (select id, col1, ifnull(col2, 'NULL') as col2
     from some_table
     where id >= 2 and id < 5
     order by id desc) as some_table;
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------+
| group_concat(id, col1, col2) |
+------------------------------+
| 2b11,3cNULL,4d25             |
+------------------------------+
```

---

Another caveat: mysql has a max-length for `group_concat` defined by the variable: `group_concat_max_len`.  In order to hash a concatenation of *n* table rows, I needed to:

1. Hash row so that it is represented in 32 bits, regardless of how many columns it has
2. Ensure that `group_concat_max_len > (n * 33)` (the extra byte accounts for added commas)
3. Hash the `group_concat` of the hashed rows.

Ultimately I ended up using the client language to examine the name, number, and nullability of each column, and then build queries like this:

```
select md5(group_concat(row_fingerprint)) from
    (select concat(id, col1, ifnull(col2, 'null')) as row_fingerprint
     from some_table
     where id >= 2 and id < 5
     order by id desc) as foo;
```

For more detail, you can poke through my code [here](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/mysqlslice/blob/master/mysqlslice/sync.py) (see function: find_diff_intervals).

Comment: I discovered later that this whole endeavor is a reinvented wheel.  What I needed was https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: I take it back.  It's still a reinvented wheel, but since my mysql user doesn't have the necessary permissions for pt-table-sync, the reinvention appears necessary.